# How to get perfect alignment when post image and message on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, image, post, message

I want to post image with message and my application name on facebook. my post must look like this:

[image]

I have applied following code

```
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bluerib);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray("picture", data);
params.putString("method", messageToPost);

facebook.request("me");
String response = facebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
```

I am successfuly able  to send both image and massage on Facebook except the application name, but I want to post it on Facebook wall, my photo must not save in Facebook photos and  I want the perfect alignment of image on left side then application name on top and my message. How to do this, do I have to use graphics API for this?  If yes how to use it?  If no so please provide me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how I done it.

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
        System.out.println("Working");
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "I am an Engineer");
        postParams.putString("caption",
                "Working very heard to make things work.");
        postParams
                .putString("description",
                        "This project is killing me, Still I am trying, and finally I got success.");
        postParams.putString("link", "http://www.kodebusters.com");
        postParams
                .putString(
                        "picture",
                        "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconslandsport/PNG/128x128/Soccer_Ball.png");

        new MYasync(postParams).execute();

    }
```

Run your network calls on AsyncTask or it may through exception

```
 class MYasync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            Bundle params;
            private String res;

            public MYasync(Bundle params) {
                super();
                this.params = params;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                System.out.println(res);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... pp) {
                try {
                    res = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
```